# Java EE 7: How many concurrent connections can WebSockets handle

Tags: java, websocket, java-ee-7

How many concurrent or long running Websocket connections can Java EE 7 Application server handle (Wildfly 8, GlassFish 4 etc)?

I know it depends on hardware (CPUs, RAM...) but what about scaling?

*Worstcase: what can i do if i have about 10000 concurrent user/connection and only one server instance (4 CPU, 16 GB RAM). Is there any common scaling techniques?*

Comment: how excessive are ur computations?

Comment: @nafas just reading from oracle/mysql database max 3 joins....

Comment: Ok, I can't give u a guaranteed answer. but I can tell you , I was struggling with few hundreds. when I was reading from mysql (my tables were big but no joins) . having said that, I had more struggle with mysql than the server. I eventually stopped at having 200 connections maxed

Comment: Typically WebSocket concurrency will not be an issue, other aspects of application would need before tuning WebSockets.

Comment: the main problem i think is the thread scheduling. perhaps there is the way to make it better. one connection/thread for multiple clients?